# preserving hot peppers without damaging heat

Tags: chili-peppers

How is this possible? My garden is starting to produce but I don't yet have enough to make into hot sauce. It would be easier to mske a large batch at the end of the season. Texture isn't important, just preserving flavor and heat since it will be sauced and canned. I am growing serrano, scotch bonnet, sweet hot cherries,  habañero, and ghost peppers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The heat in peppers (capsaicin) is quite stable.  Any number of preservation options will work, as long as you include the hottest part of the peppers which are the ribs and membranes holding the seeds.

You can choose a method based on your goals and ambition:

- [Pressure canning](http://nchfp.uga.edu/how/can_04/peppers.html)
- Dry them (follow guidelines from a reputable organization, for example links below)
- [Freezing](http://food.unl.edu/web/preservation/freezing-peppers)
- [Pickling](http://www.ext.colostate.edu/pubs/foodnut/09314.html) (and canning)

For your use case (storage for a few months prior to making hot sauce), freezing may be your best option.

See also:

- [UC Davis guide to preserving peppers](http://anrcatalog.ucdavis.edu/pdf/8004.pdf)
- [Penn State Guide](http://extension.psu.edu/food/preservation/news/2012/colorful-peppers)

Comment: I froze my jalapenos whole and it works great.

Comment: I cut the stems off before freezing. There's less mess after thawing that way.

Comment: Perfect, that's exactly what I needed. I wasn't sure if the freezing process would damage capsaicin or not. They'll be getting frozen whole (save for the stems being cut off).

Comment: @Matthew You can generally assume freezing won't damage flavor. The problem is generally texture; flavor's mostly affected if you freeze something badly (exposed to air) or the change in texture changes how you perceive a flavor.

Answer (score 2):

I strung mine up and let them dry.  Heat and flavor seem to be just fine.